# Write a JavaScript conditional statement to sort three number

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

This is my code. It's fairly simple...I do not understand why it's giving me a result of 2, 1, 3 no matter what I do and not 1, 2 , 3 when I try to sort 3, 2 and 1. Did I make a mistake somewhere in my logic or the code?

```
function sort (a, b, c) {
  if(a < b && b < c) {
    document.write(a, b , c);
  } else if (a < b && c < b) {
    document.write(a, c, b);
  } else if (b < a && a < c) {
    document.write(b, a, c);
  } else if(b < a && c < a) {
    document.write(b, c, a); 
  } else if(c < a && a < b) {
    document.write(c, a, b);
  } else {
    document.write(c, b , a);
  }
}

sort(3,2,1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following condition:

```
else if (a < b && c < b) {
    document.write(a, c, b);
  }
```

What if c is less than a? You are just checking that whether a < b and c < b, but your are not checking which number is greater between a and c.

Example :

```
var a = 9, b = 10, c = 8;
```

According to the above condition output will be:

```
output : 9,8,10
```

But correct output should be:

```
Correct output : 8,9,10
```

Similarly for condition :

```
else if(b < a && c < a) {
    document.write(b, c, a); 
  }
```

You are doing the exact same thing as above. That is why in case:

```
var a = 3, var b = 2, var c = 1
```

Your output is coming out to be : `2,1,3` because you are not comparing b with c and you simply print `b,c,a` which leads to wrong result.

What you should do is :

```
else if(b < a && c < a) {
    if(b < c){
      document.write(b, c, a); 
    } else{
       document.write(c, b, a); 
    }
 }
```

Comment: I felt it was the logic, not the code...Thank you very much, sir!

Comment: @ES glad it helped you :-)

Comment: Thanks, I am new and did not know I could do that. Will do!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other way to write your sort function manipulating if/else statements

with a,b,c you can permute them (3! possibilities)
you just write them somewhere

```
a,b,c
a,c,b
b,a,c,
b,c,a
c,a,b
c,b,a
```

you can then just test any of those arrangements...

```
function sort(a,b,c){

    if a<=b && b<=c
        print a,b,c
    else if a<=c && c<=b
        print a,c,b
    else if b<=a && a<=c
        print b,a,c
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just use the JavaScript Array `.sort()` method which would be much more concise.

Example:

```
function sort (x) {
    document.write(x.sort());
}

sort([3,2,1]);
```

or even just:

```
document.write([3,2,1].sort());
```

More information on `sort()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a conditional statements practice for if-else statements, and although there are a few ways to approach this problem, if-else statements is what I need as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to pass an **array of numbers**, and use the [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) method:

```js
const sorted = [3,2,1].sort((a,b) => a - b);
console.log(sorted);
```

Advantages of sort: it will work with any number of elements, and you don't need to make all the if's manually

Comment: I was looking to find a mistake in my code, because this is part of conditional statements practice, so it has to be a conditional if - else statement.

Answer (score -2):

```
  else if(b < a && c < a) {
      if(b < c){
        document.write(b, c, a); 
      } else{
        document.write(c, b, a); 
      }
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Well, I think this snippet answered his question and I saw other people already point out the logic flaw but didn't provide the snippet when I post this answer.